# Как передать значение переменной slug из view в controller?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

```
protected function findModelBySlug($slug) {
    if (($model = Ru::find()->where(['slug' => $slug])) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
}

public function actionView($slug) {

    return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModelBySlug($slug),
    ]);
}
```

нужно передать к примеру сюда

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class NewsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос твой вообще не понятен... перефразировал бы его.

и это бы изменил:

```
protected function findModelBySlug($slug) 
{
    if (($model = Ru::find()->where(['slug' => $slug])) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
}
```

на это

```
protected function findModelBySlug($slug) 
{
    if (($model = Ru::find()->where('slug=:slug', [':slug' => $slug])) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }
}
```

а то получается, то, что передается пользователем то и летит в базу в запрос сразу

Comment: Спасибо поправил!

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть некая неястность для меня. 
Но судя по всему это 2 разных контроллера. 
в `actionView()`  вы отдаете вид и передеаете туда модель, если вы хотите с этого экшене перенаправиться в `NewsController actionIndex` , то пропишите так

```
return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['news/index', 'model' => $this->findModelBySlug($slug)]);
```

само собой если у вам в базовом варианте идете рендер вида, то вам нужно задать некое условие при котором вы хотите делать перенаправление

а в actionIndex можете написать так `actionIndex($model = null)`
тоесть если вы не передадите параметр - ошибки не будет

Comment: Да 2 разных контроллера, вообщем ситуация такая, первый контроллер с view из базы данных берет slug строит ссылку такого вида http://site.ru/ru/moscow , где slug это moscow.

Comment: Потом при переходе на http://site.ru/ru/moscow/news , чтобы там отобразилось именно moscow к примеру name или title, content.

Comment: в базе записаны в slug города, так же есть поля id, name, slug, title, content, alias

Comment: вы строите урл moscow/news как ваш контроллер  понимает что новости нужно тянуть для москвы? покажите код пожалуйста